# Unwanted special characters added automatically in my FCK Editor

Tags: php, special-characters, fckeditor

Some of the CZECH special characters like ž and white spaces are replaced by the character Â. I have tried changing the encoding of editor to utf-8. But the CZECH special character ž disappeared at that time. The default charset used now is iso-8859-1. Still the issue persists.

If you have a solution,  I would be truly grateful.

Thanks a lot....

Comment: Make sure `magic_quotes_gpc` is off or not on server.

Comment: Thanks..let me check plz...